# Nested Linq query returns three times the result?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I am trying to work with dynamic data and running into some odd things with LINQ that I can't find much information online. I want to point out that this issue I run into happens on any nested collection.

I want to take a collection of dynamic data, then filter it with a where query. That where query simply checks all the values to see if it contains "FL" and then I want it to return the dynamic collection... not just the fields that contain FL.

I've explicitly put in the type in the where clause to make  it easier to read online, it is redundant otherwise.

```
        IEnumerable<dynamic> query = from agent in agentRecords
            from values in (ExpandoObject)agent
            where ((KeyValuePair<string, object>)values).Value.ToString().Contains("FL")
            select agent;
```

The query works, but returns **3 times** the expected result.(I get 9 agents instead of 3, multiple duplicates.)

I am able to filter it by calling distinct, but something tells me I am not doing this right.

The other way to do this is by using LINQ extension methods

```
var result = agentRecords.Cast<ExpandoObject>().Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Value.ToString().Contains("FL")));
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics, there are multiple examples of "multiple/nested from" linq queries and it doesn't seem to run into this duplicate result problem... what am I overlooking?

Comment: Just fyi, the two different syntaxes are called "Query" and "Method" syntax, respectively. Could you please clarify if both syntaxes are returning the same result?  It doesn't seem that your Method syntax is doing your multiple from clause.

Comment: You are returning agent every time each `values.Value` contains "FL". You need to return an agent when any `values.Value` contains "FL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cross joining each agent with its collection of `values`, test each agent once:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> query = from agent in agentRecords
                             where (from values in (ExpandoObject)agent
                                    select ((KeyValuePair<string, object>)values).Value.ToString().Contains("FL")).Any()
                             select agent;
```

Lambda syntax does seem clearer to me, which looks to be identical to your expression:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> query2 = agentRecords.Where(agent => ((ExpandoObject)agent).Any(((KeyValuePair<string, object>)values).Value.ToString().Contains("FL")));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, now it makes a lot more sense to me. The reason why I was getting multiple results was because there was multiple "matches" to the key of "FL". By putting that query syntax in parenthesis and have it test the condition of having any elements, returning a bool... makes a lot more sense.  I knew how to do it in Lambda syntax, but was just trying to wrap my head around query syntax because sometimes it's easier to write out what I want that way... seems more human friendly I suppose.

Comment: I agree query syntax has its comprehension advantages, especially with `let` (though I supposed that is hiding the potential performance issues that lambda syntax makes explicit) and especially when translating from SQL, though I wish C# supported more constructs directly like VB does.

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in agentRecords
where (from i in (ExpandoObject)a
       where (((KeyValuePair<string, object>)i).Value.ToString().Contains("FL")
       select i).Count() > 0
select a;
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer